# Retrieve Product Info from Barcode

Tags: c#, web-services

How can I retrieve product information for a given barcode (GTIN)? Is there a webservice for example to which I can submit a barcode that will return information for that product? I am particularly interested in obtaining information for grocery/food products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about sending barcode text instead of picture? You can create your own barcode service. But ofcourse this service must be talking with a DB which has barcode information.

1- Read barcode text with barcode reader machine

2- Send read text (for ex 41651321513) to your web-service or any service which is talking with DB (to get any result, your barcode must be known by your DB)

3- Get your barcode information.

Or you can ask for a web-service from any supermarket :) (which is connected to supermarket's food dataBase)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are there any good free (to download) barcode DB ?  or a good affordable one for that matter. (without price info:)

Comment: Every DataBase can be a barcode DB :) (SQL,Oracle,Access...)

Comment: lol .. really .. where do they hide the barcodes at... oh .. you mean fill it myself. That's practical.

Comment: Yes you need to fill it yourself :) or as I said ask from any supermarket to get web service

Answer (score 2):

What about using Google Search API for Shopping http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/search/
I haven't done it myself yet but it appears you can pass the barcode (in text format) as the gtin property and get back product information in XML format.

You could also try upcdatabase.com or ean-search.org or https://www.semantics3.com/

Comment: That API "is now sunset for all users other than Google Commerce Search customers"